# What happens to java output stream when jar is double clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jar

I have a java application with a swing UI. It also outputs to the console using System.out.println. My question is what happens to the output when the jar file is double clicked. Is it stored in the java VM memory and does it take up resources? or is it discarded and not stored anywhere?

Comment: It goes out through the process's stdout stream, which means unless something is reading it, it is basically discarded, it is not buffered in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no console attached when you double click on the jar. So `System.out.println` will go nowhere. Instead use a logging framework.

Comment: Nowhere as in it is not stored in the memory either?

Comment: Nope. It is just discarded.